# Book about a journalist on the trail of an immortality drug

Tags: story-identification, books, immortality

There is a story set in the near future where there is developed an immortality drug. The protagonist is a journalist on the trail of this scoop. Maybe the opening of the story is them interviewing a wealthy contact about this secret technology. The story goes on with the whole world getting the drug and society realigning around humanity being unable to die but by injury, either by accident or design. Please help me find this book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "*[The Postmortal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10673576-the-postmortal)*" by Drew Magary.

> Imagine a near future where a cure for aging is discovered and-after much political and moral debate-made available to people worldwide. Immortality, however, comes with its own unique problems-including evil green people, government euthanasia programs, a disturbing new religious cult, and other horrors.
>
> [image: front cover of the book, showing a skeletal figure in a robe, as the stereotypical Death. It is bent double with the blade of a scythe through its back and protruding from the front]

I didn't go with this originally because I was also thinking of another book that seemed similar (that I can't remember title of).